# Replace All in Javascript is not working?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to replace smiles in a string with Javascript and this is a line from my code:

```
res = res.replace(/;\)/g, function myFunction(x){
                               return '<img src="/emoticons/wink.png" >'; 
                          });
```

It's working fine and when I send `;)` it gives me the smile

**But the Problem is that when I send `');` it works also and give me the same smile**

I mean when I send for example `Simplemessage('sometext');` it change it to `example Simplemessage('sometext'{Smile};`

Comment: A list but when I just stop that specific line every thing change to be working => The problem in that Line (Thanks in advance)

Comment: Sorry I'm not good in Regrex so could you write the example and I will try it (Thank you so much for your help)

Comment: `'` probably gets converted to `&apos;`, effectively turning this into `&apos;);`.

Comment: Is `res` a HTML string? [You can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630)

Comment: @Xufox You are really a Genius, HHHHHHHHHHHH that's it that's the problem it's JSON

Comment: Note you should only use regex on a *plain* text.

Comment: @Xufox Thank you so much for your help, But what to do, Could you help please :)

Comment: @KhalilBz I’m not exactly sure what the process for displaying the message is, but I would make that replacement, before the string gets added to HTML. It looks like you’re getting `res` from the `innerHTML` of some element; I’d do it before setting the `innerHTML`. But I can’t see the details, so I can’t say for sure.

Comment: @Xufox It's converted to JSON in PHP and After getting the Ajax Request I directly replace all the smiles, And thank you so much, Please answer with your comment to mark it as best answer if you want ^_^

Comment: @Xufos that was amazing, it'd have taken me days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please excuse how messy this is - but I assure you that this is about as good as you're going to get.

```regex
(?<!&#([0-46-9]\d|5[0-8]))(?<!&#\d{3})(?<!&[a-z]{2})(?<!&[a-z]{3})(?<!&[a-z]{4})(?<!&[a-z]{5})(?<!&[a-z]{6})(?<!&[a-z]{7})(?<!&[a-z]{8});\)
```

Basically it makes sure that the `)` is not preceded by an alternate symbol, such as `&apos;` or `&#39;`, except for the unique case in which it is `&#59;`, which is the symbol for semicolon (and thus, it **should** work.

Since it uses a negative lookbehind, I have to (unfortunately) duplicate a piece of the code, as it cannot be variable length. The longest ascii entity in html is `thetasym`, which is 8 characters long, so I must duplicate it that many times.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/hkJ9yT/1

Let me know if this one works! (and massive kudos to Xufos for figuring out the `&apos;` thing)